# Get selected item of an select list

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm an apex beginner and I have a question.

I have a blank page and I want to add 2 select lists.
Like this:

[image]

The values of the second list are dependent on the selected value of the first list.
How can I access this selected value?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you are looking for is Cascading Select Lists, and this comes natively in Apex 4.0 and up. If you are on a lower version, BoeroBoy's way may get you there.

Take a look at the blog post done by Patrick Wolf, who is on the apex dev team.
Pre 4.0: http://www.inside-oracle-apex.com/generic-solution-for-cascading-select-listslovs/
4.0 and up: http://www.inside-oracle-apex.com/oracle-apex-4-0-cascading-lovsselect-lists/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a few ways.  You can make the top select box submit the page during a selection change and then the bottom select list will be refreshed with your new options, but that will take a submit and refresh of the entire page.  You can also apply some Javascript.

I suggest you start reading here:

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/apex/r41/dynactions/dynactions.htm

A more specific example of Dependent Select Lists is here:
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/hol08/apexweb20/ajax_otn.htm#t1

Hope this helps!